# Wireless card advanced properties

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers

I have 2 laptops, one with a Broadcom 802.11n wireless card, the other with an Intel 5300 802.11n.
I have often wondered about all the properties in the drivers' "Advanced" tab (see image) but could not google a satisfying documentation source.
[image: Broadcom advanced properties]

Should the card be "40Mhz intolerant"? What is "Afterburner" and why is it disabled? Which setting should I change to enable the Broadcom to see my 5.2Mhz network, which the Intel works well with? Etc. etc.

In short, can someone point me to a source explaining all those properties? Maybe even a list of recommendations for the best values to gain the best wireless performance?

TIA,

Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much hunting about I was able to locate a Dell document that describes a lot of that screen-cap:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/network/p70008/EN/vista_7/props.htm

**Afterburner:** A proprietary Broadcom feature that adds speed to G networks ([details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/125_High_Speed_Mode))
**40MHz intolerance:** An N setting, it affects how it deals with overlapping G networks. This kind of thing may come into play in crowded airspaces, as it may annoy your neighbors.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep the question open for a while to see if I can get any optimization links, but if not - it's yours.